# How to dynamical change the html using jquery get method in ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

Below is the code snippet. I have used to fetch some attributes from html and passing it to sever using AJAX. On sucess of the AJAX I need to return some content on Html Page.

```
var hotel=$( "#listHotel option:selected" ).val();      
$.ajax({
            url: "/getHotels",
            contentType: "application/xml; charset=utf-8",
            data: {'hotel':hotel},          
            type: "GET",
            success: function(response){                
                var r= JSON.parse(response);                
                var rating =r.message   
                alert(rating);          
                $("#rate").html("Ratings : "+rating);
                $("#rate").show('slow');                
                console.log(rating);
            },
            error: function(error){
                alert(response);
                console.log(error);
              }
          });
```

is it possible to dynamically change the `HTML` using jquery `get` method.
Because the below scripts are not working

```
$("#rate").html("Ratings : "+rating);
$("#rate").show('slow');
```

Comment: ***... not working*** is not descriptive enough for any one of us to help you. Is the data returned `json` or `xml`? What is the output of `console.log( response )`? Do you see any errors?

Comment: That should work as is if the alert actually shows the correct rating (and you have an element - and only one element on the page with id `rate`)

Comment: As i am using get methodin AJAX  the page is reloading automatically so the html is changed

Comment: but still i am getting the alert.

Answer (score 2):

try defining the `dataType` of your ajax call as `json`:

```
var hotel=$( "#listHotel option:selected" ).val();      
$.ajax({
            url: "/getHotels",
            contentType: "application/xml; charset=utf-8",
            data: {'hotel':hotel},
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(response){                
                var r= response;
                var rating =r.message   
                alert(rating);          
                $("#rate").html("Ratings : "+rating);
                $("#rate").show('slow');                
                console.log(rating);
            },
            error: function(error){
                alert(response);
                console.log(error);
              }
          });
```

Comment: Its not working. After the AJAX call made the page starts to load and finally the changed html `$("#rate").html("Ratings : "+rating);`  is no longer  persist